# Error de directivas al tratar de reproducir archivos .mp3 en c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Actualmente quiero reproducir archivos de audio en mp3 y ya tengo fragmentos del código que en teoría deberían de funcionar.

Codigo Actual:

```
using WMPLib; ------ Error

    public void timerson() {
        MessageBox.Show("Cada cierto tiempo segundos");
        WindowsMediaPlayer myplayer = new WindowsMediaPlayer(); --- Error
        myplayer.URL = @"C:\Users\david\Music\Cancion.mp3";
        myplayer.controls.play();
}
```

Solo que me marca el siguiente error:

> Falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado

Comment: Puedes revisar si la librería `WMPLib` que quieres usar la tienes referenciada en el proyecto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WMPLib viene del componente COM de Windows Media Player, tienes que añadir una referencia a la librería COM wmp.dll en c:\Windows\System32 para que tu programa funcione, En caso de que no la tengas en tu computadora.

Necesitas agregar la referencia a `Windows Media Player`, con esto debe de reconocer el `namespace` WPLib.
Esta referencia la encuentras en la categoría `COM` al momento de agregar referencias.

Debes hacerlo como en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]